# PayPal cannot process this transaction because of seller's website

Tags: php, paypal, live

After successful Sandbox testing for Website Payments Standard, I'm going live now. When I click on a "Buy Now" button,  I should be able to see a page that shows me the total quantity on the left, and allows me to log in using PayPal on the right.

But I just get the following page, which also says "Test Site" at the top, although I'm no longer referring to the sandbox:

[image]

The error is: `Paypal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website.`

I've done the following things:

1. Made sure I've changed the API endpoints to live production (basically, eliminate "sandbox" from the URLs.
2. Made sure I'm using the seller API crendentials from my seller account (not sandbox test API).
3. I'm using an IPN listener and have set `$listener->user_sandbox` to `false` (although I don't think the listener is even loaded yet at this stage).

By the way, if it matters, I'm using PayPal's ButtonManagerAPI to dynamically create hosted buttons, and I'm using NVP API calls with PHP. Everything worked as expected in the sandbox. This was my relevant API code:

```
"METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature&BUTTONCODE=HOSTED&BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW&L_BUTTONVAR1=amount=".$usd_total
```

Comment: This is most likely being caused by something that is being passed over.  Can you provide what you are passing over minus your API credentials, or the returned button code so that we can test this and see what may be causing the issue.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad this is what I'm passing over: `METHOD=BMCreateButton&VERSION=98.0&PWD=$pwd&USER=$user&SIGNATURE=$signature&BUTTONCODE=HOSTED&BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW&L_BUTTONVAR1=amount=14.13&L_BUTTONVAR2=return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeej.com.sa%2Fprintshop%2Fcheckout4_confirm.php&L_BUTTONVAR3=cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeej.com.sa%2Fprintshop%2Fcancel.php&L_BUTTONVAR4=no_shipping=1&L_BUTTONVAR5=notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeej.com.sa%2Fprintshop%2Fipn.php&L_BUTTONVAR6=custom=33`

Answer (score 0):

I tested your API request against my account and it is working correctly.  It correctly generates a button, and then I am able to go through with a buyer account and make a purchase, so it looks like the issue is with the account you are using to generate the button.  Can you provide either the test sandbox email, or the merchant id for the account that you generated the test sandbox credentials from so that I can take a look at the account and see what the issue may be?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I couldn't reply earlier because my company was going through some changes including changing our hosting service, so I was waiting till we're stable. The email login with which I created test sandbox accounts is ahmed@zeej.com.sa. Please take a look and let me know what the issue is asap. Since we're up on the new hosting service and our services are ready, we're trying to launch as soon as the online payment thing works out. Thanks!

Comment: I am not seeing any issues with the account, and the API call is working for me with my credentials.  Can you try creating a clear text / non hosted button to see if you get the same issue.  If you do, can you provide the HTML code for the newly created button so that I can test with it further.

Comment: Is there any email address I can contact you on? We have a new problem. I was able to get PayPal running live, and we've also made a test purchase. Apparently the purchase worked fine, but the problem is that the IPN listener I set up didn't work or send any notifications at all, although it ran as expected during sandbox testing. I can give you the reference number of the purchase just done, why did it not hit the IPN listner? This was the transaction ID for the payment done on our website zeej.com.sa/printshop: "36V49266KU851411T". And the API username: abdulaziz_api1.zeej.com.sa

Comment: I think the merchant email address is info@zeej.com.sa

Comment: You can open up a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts and provide all of the details in the ticket.  Than if you can post the ticket number back here I will take a look at the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message until I removed the ng-model reference (angularJS) in the button html code.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually getting this issue from simply not having the correct product ID in the form. Once I updated that it worked for me.

Hope this helps!